# Bash script to check if pipreqs is installed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pip

I'm working on a bash script to detect if [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) is installed on a system and install [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) if it isn't installed.

this is what I have so far;

```
if command -v pipreqs > /dev/null; then
  echo "pipreqs is already installed"
else
  echo "pipreqs is not installed, installing now"
  pip install pipreqs
fi
```

line 1 doesn't seem to work how I intend it.

I'm new to scripting.

Comment: In what way is it not working? I don't have `pipreqs` installed on my system, and `command -v pipreqs` exits with an error code, which seems like exactly the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3):

Testing the `pipreqs` command is available within the `$PATH` environment is not reliable. It can give you false negative, because `command -v pipreqs` will fail if the `pipreqs` command is not within one of the paths within the `$PATH` environment variable.

If pipreqs is installed by a user account locally with `pip install --user pipreqs`, it will try to place the `pipreqs` command within the `~/.local/bin` directory if it is registered to the `$PATH` environment variable. But it may not be available to the `$PATH` and fail `command -v pipreqs`

If you need to check that the `pipreq` package is installed, even without a `pipreqs` command in `$PATH`, then you could do the check with `pip` like this:

```bash
if pip --quiet show pipreqs 2> /dev/null; then
  echo "pipreqs is already installed"
else
  echo "pipreqs is not installed, installing now"
  pip install --user pipreqs
fi
```

You could find more info on managing python project dependencies if it is what you are trying to do with `pipreqs` here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/managing-dependencies/

Comment: `pip show pipreqs` is also not reliable — `pipreqs` could be installed with a different version of Python and not available to default `pip`.

Comment: Should do both then: `command -v pipreqs > /dev/null || pip --quiet show pipreqs 2> /dev/null`. May add user mode install check as well.

Comment: `type -P` is also better than `command -v` in my opinion since latter also returns true on builtins and functions.